# Zend Framework: How do I remove the decorators on a Zend Form Hidden Element?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I'm trying to remove the default decorators on a hidden form element. By default, the hidden element is displayed like this:

```
<dt>Hidden Element Label (if I had set one)</dt>
<dd><input type="hidden" name="foobar" value="1" id="foobar"></dd>
```

I don't want my hidden element to take up space on my page. I want to remove all the default decorators so all I'm left with is the input tag.

```
<input type="hidden" name="foobar" value="1" id="foobar">
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376188/zend-framework-zendform-decorator-issue

Comment: It's actually a different question, but it's very similar.

Comment: Read the actual question - it's the same.

Comment: removing all and removing one decorator may be the same if all you have is one decorator, but it's not the same if you have more than one.

Comment: Answered this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376188/zend-framework-zend-form-decorator-issue/4635352#4635352)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

For hidden field you need only one decorator - ViewHelper:

```
$field = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('id');
$field->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper'));
```

This will render only the input field, without Dt-Dd wrapper and label.

Answer (score 32):

From the [Zend Element Decorators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.decorators) documentation:

> Default Decorators Do Not Need to Be
>   Loaded
>
> By default, the default decorators are
>   loaded during object initialization.
>   You can disable this by passing the
>   'disableLoadDefaultDecorators' option
>   to the constructor:
>
> ```
> $element = new Zend_Form_Element('foo', 
>     array('disableLoadDefaultDecorators' => true)
> );
> ```

Comment: Handy!  I used it like 
    $this->addElement('hidden','article_id', array('disableLoadDefaultDecorators' => true)); that in my init method.

Comment: Using this solution, the `<input type="hidden">` field does not display at all for me.

Answer (score 24):

I use this

```
$element->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
```

to get rid of the dt dd tags around specific elements

Answer (score 6):

// based on above - a simple function to add a hidden element to $this form

```
/**
 * Add Hidden Element
 * @param $field
 * @param value
 * @return nothing - adds hidden element
 * */
public function addHid($field, $value){     
    $hiddenIdField = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden($field);
    $hiddenIdField->setValue($value)
          ->removeDecorator('label')
          ->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');     
    $this->addElement($hiddenIdField);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When you have a lot of hidden inputs best answer is the following:

```
$elements = $this->getElements();
foreach ($elements as $elem)
    if ($elem instanceof Zend_Form_Element_Hidden)
        $elem->removeDecorator('label')->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');
```

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in other posts `setDisableLoadDefaultDecorators(true)` doesn't work if they're already loaded... BUT `clearDecorators()` does!

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get disableLoadDefaultDecorators to work quite right. Here's a solution I came up with.

```
$hiddenIdField = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('id');
$hiddenIdField->setValue($portalId)
              ->removeDecorator('label')
              ->removeDecorator('HtmlTag');
```

In the HTML, the hidden field appears without any extra tags around it.

```
...
<dt><label for="password" class="required">Password</label></dt>
<dd><input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" /></dd>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" id="id" />
...
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that it is not xhtml compliant

Answer (score 2):

here is what takeme2web from http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=225848.0
suggests

$yourhiddenzendformelement->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper'));

Answer (score 2):

Using only a single "ViewHelper" decorator will generate invalid markup if you're still using the `<dl>` wrapper. Another approach is outlined in [ZF-2718](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2718?focusedCommentId=40837&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#action_40837). This adds hidden fields to a subform that is wrapped in a `<dd>`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, 2012 and still the same issue. If you remove the decorators, the html won't validate. If you leave them, the hidden elements take up space. In all of my projects I have a CSS helper .hidden, so I just apply it to the `<dd>` and unset the label:

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('foo', array('value' => 'bar'));
$element->removeDecorator('Label');
$element->getDecorator('HtmlTag')->setOption('class', 'hidden');
```

Valid html(5), nice looking forms. This can also go into a custom decorator for the hidden fields.

**EDIT**

This is how I put it into my own form element:

```
class Exanto_Form_Element_Hidden extends Zend_Form_Element_Hidden
{
    public function render(Zend_View_Interface $view = null)
    {
        $this->removeDecorator('Label');
        $this->getDecorator('HtmlTag')->setOption('class', 'hidden');
        return parent::render($view);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    foreach ($this->getElements() as $element) {

        $decorator = $element->getDecorator('label');
        if (!$decorator) {
            continue;
        }
        $decorator->removeOption('tag');
    }
```